# Python - Split point is an array of words

Tags: python

I want to split a sentence based upon words currently stored in an array. The array stores the words that I want to act as a split point. Can I use an array as split point using regex?

Example:

```
array=['and','also','but']
```

Text file:

```
I am new to Python and I need help. I am also asking a question.
```

Required output:

```
I need help
asking a question
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? There are a few steps to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re.split()` function:

```
import re
array = ['and','also','but']
sentence = "I am new to Python and I need help. I am also asking a question."
result = re.split("|".join(array), sentence)
```

I will add a trim:

```
result = [x.strip() for x in result]
print(result)
```

Comment: Your script results in `['I am new to Python', 'I need help. I am', 'asking a question.']` while the @blahhh something like `['I need help'
, 'asking a question']`. Granted, @blahhh doesn't really explain the logic resulting in their output.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an adaptation of @hurturk solution - that will produce @blahhh requested output.
Since my crystal ball broke last week, whether this algorithm is what @blahhh intended, is anyone's guess.

```
from __future__ import print_function

import re
array = ['and', 'also', 'but']
separators = ['\.', '\;', '\?', '\!']
sentence = "I am new to Python and I need help. I am also asking a question."

sentences = re.split("|".join(separators), sentence)
for sentence in sentences:
    result = re.split("|".join(array), sentence)
    result = [x.strip() for x in result]
    print(result[-1])
```

where the output is:

```
I need help
asking a question
```